# GridSearchCV with Random Forest- Invalid Parameter Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to find best parameters using GridSearchCV but I'm getting Invalid parameter error.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn import metrics        

clf= RandomForestRegressor()

parameters={'clf__n_estimators': (50, 100, 150),
        'clf__max_depth': (50, 150, 250),
        'clf__min_samples_split': (1,3),
        'clf__min_samples_leaf': (1,2,3) }

grid_search=GridSearchCV(clf,parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x,y)
grid_search.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

The error is as below;

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter clf for estimator RandomForestRegressor(). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

I don't see a reason for this error. I checked the parameters they are all seem correct. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

A basic search in the documentation [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

"Dictionary with parameters names (str) as keys and lists of parameter settings to try as values"

which means

```
parameters={'n_estimators': [50, 100, 150],
            'max_depth': [50, 150, 250],
            'min_samples_split': [1,3],
            'min_samples_leaf': [1,2,3] }
```

Comment: Actually I tried that either but it gives ' ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'housemaid' ' error.

Comment: then the problem is in the housemaid feature, a categorical feature maybe?

Comment: What is the housemaid feature? This is the first time I get this error since I'm new to gridsearch and cv practices

Comment: 'housemaid` is not any object in GridSearchCV, it's something in your data.